# java stream parallel read/write

Tags: java, io, stream, copy

i want to stream an audio file from the internet and play it.
I am using this code:

```
int readBytes = 0;
    byte[] audioBuffer = new byte[this.EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];

    readBytes = in.read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);
    while (readBytes != -1) {
        readBytes = in.read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);
        if (readBytes >= 0) {
            dataLine.write(audioBuffer, 0, readBytes);
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that when the Stream is reading, it is not writing. Therefore the music is not playing for a short time every few seconds. 
So i was wondering if there is a way for the stream to simultaneously read from the inputstream and write to the dataline so the writing is never paused for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is. When you are trying to do any 2 things or more at one time , then your are looking for multithreading .

It's not something you can learn in 5 minutes though so you should read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

for example :

```
public class Printer implements Runnable{

 String name;
 public Printer(String name){
 this.name=name;
 }
 public void run(){

  while(true){
   System.out.println("i am thread"+name);
  //in your case read or write bytes to dataline here;
  }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
 Printer print1= new Printer("a");
 Printer print2 = new Printer("b");
 new Thread(print1).start();
 new Thread(print2).start();
 }
}
```

this would keep printing "i am thread a" " i am thread b " in no defined order since its not synchronized , so it could give aabbbbaababaaba rather than ababababab, but the idea is that they are both running at same time .

this is just a rough example on how you would use threads , its missing synchronization and safety and stuff you should read about before tackling threads .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i am familiar with Threads. So i assume there is no way build in the java api to do this.

Comment: if you're looking for an api to do streaming i would recommed vlcJ or xuggler , i've had luck with these before. vlcJ is easiest API i could think of .

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether this is possible or not, but does `dataLine.write(audioBuffer, 0, in.read());` do what you want ?

Comment: although this looks like its being done at same time ... it is not.The program will do in.read() then pass the answer to write() .it's basic programming logic .